# Как подключить бота дискорд к каналу по id?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Необходимо настроить бота на 1 голосовой и 1 текстовый каналы.

Не понимаю, как заставить его подключаться к определённому каналу.
Использую:

```
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
```

Пробовал указать в значении id, но он же не дурак, чтобы использовать .connect() со строкой.
Если это вывести через print, то на выходе получаю лишь название канала.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить: pip install discord.py[voice]

```
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
await channel.connect()
```

Мне помогло